# Can photos be put in frames on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, pictures

Can one put photos in plastic frames that have either swiveling plastic latches or soft metal bending latches that open the back and let a photo be placed between the glass and the back without glue?

Comment: What would be the possible concern?

Comment: @mbloch No idea, maybe Make, maybe Boneh maybe something else, Halachah is so unpredictable. Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the type of photo and the type of frame. **A rare/previous/important picture or a delicate frame would fall in the *halachic* category of *mukze chisaron kis* ("a loss of the pocket") and could not be moved.**

This category of *muktze* relates to objects that are valuable to their owner (regardless of their monetary value), that don't have a specific/permitted use on Shabbat and that people are particular not to employ for alternative uses (see e.g., [Mishna Brura 308:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.308.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Expensive and/or fragile objects are almost certainly included in that category. See R Daniel Braude's [Learn Shabbos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1988022304), pp. 455ff.

R Dovid Ribiat (the 39 melochos, vol. 1, p. 47) actually explicitly mentions delicate family photographs as examples of *mukze chisaron kis*.

**If the frame is a cheap plastic frame and the picture unimportant, they do not fall into this category and can be handled.** There is no issue of *bone* or *make be patish* as you are not building something new when opening/closing the frame (like a folding chair).

Of course, and especially for intermediary cases, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: "particular not to employ for alternative uses" could be pretty inclusive, even of pictures that are "cheap", if they are expected never to leave the wall/shelf/pedestal/shrine.

Comment: indeed there are *poskim* (e.g., Chazon Ish, R Yitzchak Berkovits) who forbid moving or readjusting pictures on the wall for that reason. R Moshe Feinstein is lenient

Comment: Thank you, an interesting observation. How about a difference between a new blank frame and replacing an existing photo - would there be a difference? Can placing a photo into a blank new frame considered Makeh?

Comment: @AlBerko I do not believe so and did not see anything like this when I reviewed the *halachot* of *make bepatish* for this answer. The *kli* is finished before you put the picture, it is called a frame before